# One thread in Real Time priority freezes Windows 7.

Tags: windows-7, real-time, freeze

I just moved from WinXP to Win7.
My software needs to have real time response to I/O so it makes a busy-wait in one thread (which has affinity to run on one CPU).

The result is 100% CPU on one of the cores and 0% CPU for others, on Winows XP it worked just fine. 
In Windows 7 the system freezes. (The software is a console application, for Windows application it behaves a bit different. only if the main thread make busy-wait without peeking messages it freezes)

Any ideas ?

Comment: IIRC the 'system' thread in XP worked on Real time priority. In Win7 its lowered (probably to Normal) so you're system freezes.

Answer (score 1):

So you're using a non real-time OS for realtime I/O. Simply put the code isn't working correctly and should do a non busy-wait (change to a sleep-wait) loop and change the thread timer settings to something that is realtime enough.

See this question to setup windows for millisecond precision on a timer callback.

[How to trigger a C# function at a certain time with millisecond precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705157/how-to-trigger-a-c-function-at-a-certain-time-with-millisecond-precision/6705314#6705314)